# Repeated value in align environment with pythontex

Tags: align, pythontex

In following MWE, I expect the value of `Amb. Temp.` to be 50 but it doesn't.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
s_base_ONAN = 18
s_base_ONAF1 = 24
s_base_ONAF = 30
u_os = 63
u_us = 20
u_range = 15
steps = 9
v_g = "Ynd11"
amb_temp = 50
install = 1500
\end{pycode}

    \begin{align*}
        & S = \unit[\py{s_base_ONAF}]{MVA}, \quad \text{ONAN, ONAF1, ONAF2}\
        (\py{s_base_ONAN}/\py{s_base_ONAF1}/\py{s_base_ONAF}) \\
        & \unit[\py{u_os}(\pm \py{u_range}\% \text{ in } \pm \py{steps}
        \text{ steps})/\py{u_us}]{kV}, \quad
        \text{\py{v_g}} \\
        & \text{Amb.\ Temp.} = \unit[\py{amb_temp}]{^\circ C}, \quad
        \text{Installation Level}= \unit[\py{install}]{m}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `\mbox` it works

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
s_base_ONAN = 18
s_base_ONAF1 = 24
s_base_ONAF = 30
u_os = 63
u_us = 20
u_range = 15
steps = 9
v_g = "Ynd11"
amb_temp = 50
install = 1500
\end{pycode}

    \begin{align*}
        & S = \unit[\py{s_base_ONAF}]{MVA}, \quad \text{ONAN, ONAF1, ONAF2}\
        (\py{s_base_ONAN}/\py{s_base_ONAF1}/\py{s_base_ONAF}) \\
        & \unit[\py{u_os}(\pm \py{u_range}\% \text{ in } \pm \py{steps}
        \text{ steps})/\py{u_us}]{kV}, \quad
        \mbox{\py{v_g}} \\
        & \text{Amb.\ Temp.} = \unit[\py{amb_temp}]{^\circ C}, \quad
        \text{Installation Level}= \unit[\py{install}]{m}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

`\text` uses `\mathchoice` so is evaluated 4 times, this confuses pythontex's mapping of python results back to tex it seems. You could report this at the pythontex repository.